# Deploying Docker Image to Heroku

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, heroku

I keep running into this error when I try and deploy a docker image (Python 3.10 and MongoDB) using the following commands:

```
heroku container:login
heroku create ttcv1
heroku container:push web -a ttcv1
heroku container:release web -a ttcv1
```

Image gets "pushed" but I get an Application error page:

[image]

Log below:

```
`2022-06-07T17:26:12.468116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python3`
2022-06-07T17:26:13.339555+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-06-07T17:26:13.396838+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-06-07T17:26:13.405363+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-06-07T17:26:29.712735+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python3`
2022-06-07T17:26:31.750611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-06-07T17:26:31.857509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-06-07T17:26:33.315159+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ttcv1.herokuapp.com request_id=bb032403-08cb-42dc-a8a5-8f683601a45a fwd="49.37.171.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-06-07T17:26:33.761854+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ttcv1.herokuapp.com request_id=b7217391-0c68-4315-9c73-c3e687dbbe01 fwd="49.37.171.163" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`
```

Flask app run:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'mysecret'
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Here's my docker-compose file

```
    app:
  build: .
  command: python -u app.py
  
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: mongo:latest
  hostname: dstudio
  environment:
    - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=dstudio
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
```

My docker file (one of the threads asked changing it to docker.web; tried that too)

```
FROM python:3.7
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Finally, the Procfile (if it matters)

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:${PORT} wsgi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance I would recommend setting up an alternative file to handle your deployment different from the Docker Compose file you're using for local dev. Taking a look at the heroku docs you can see they [recommend setting up a heroku.yml](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml) that would manage building your flask server for you.

That file would look something like this:

```
build:
  docker:
    app: Dockerfile
```

To manage your mongo instance you could either use a heroku add on, although all of the mongo instances look like they cost money. I'd suggest setting up a [mongodb atlas cluster](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/use-atlas-on-heroku/) and then configure your heroku ENV vars to tell the flask server to hit the mongodb cluster. That way it would be free until you started going over their rate limits.

If you're looking for more control over deployment where you can manage everything with a single docker compose file, heroku might not be the best fit for you and I'd encourage you to look at an alternative service.

Comment: Thanks. This really is a good direction. I realized Heroku is not a one-stop shop, and I should look elsewhere.